# How to superpose a created map and coordinates?

Tags: google-maps

I created a route with Google Maps and save it in my maps.
In parallel, I recorded GPS coordinates with a device.
In order to analyse the quality of my device, I would like to import or superpose the coordinates on the created map.
Is it possible to do that and how ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Google Maps API and build a small application as per your requirements.

There is no easy way than this.